# rich:component not found in Richfaces 5.0.0.Alpha3

Tags: richfaces, components, wildfly

I'm trying to migrate project from Richfaces 4.3.6 to 5.0.0.Alpha3.

I deleted all dependencies of old version Richfaces and add new dependency in `pom.xml` of my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Alpha3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, `rich:component` in my `xhtml` pages doesn't work. It is highlighted in `Intellij Idea` and when I try to open `xhtml` page I get this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Function 'rich:component' not found.
```

When I try `4.5.0` version of Richfaces `rich:component` works correctly. Its dependency looks similar:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using `Wildfly 8.1`, version  of `Mojarra 2.2.6`.

What is problem? Can anybody helps?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the problem. In old versions of Richfaces namespaces in `xhtml` pages was:
`xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"` 
and
    `xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"`.

And when you wrote button (for example), you used:
    `<a4j:commandButton`.

Now, in new version you need to change namespaces. 
You should write only:
    `xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org"`.

And then you should write 
    `<rich:commandButton`.

My error was in `commandButton` and `rich:component` was not found. Now it is working.